# MySQL server on Ubuntu 19.04 WITHOUT the MariaDB engine

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I need to upgrade/move a 5.7 version of mysql on ubuntu 18.04 so that it's still 5.7 but does not use the MariaDB engine. Everything I can find online talks about moving from Mysql to MariaDB, not the other way around. I'm not even sure there is a way to do this.

I'm stuck with having to install a webapp that uses MySQL but cannot use MariaDB. The creators of the app have assured the user community that it's "an easy upgrade" but then provide no details.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `uses MySQL but cannot use MariaDB` why do you think that you can’t use MariaDB? The one shipped with 18.04 is a drop in replacement and shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: They probably provide no details because there *are* no details - it'll likely run just fine on Maria.